# How can I add the Name to the Firebase user?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I can save the email and the password with Firebase Authentication. But how can I add and save the name of the user after registering?

I tried to put a name in the user, and store this in firebase.

my code:

```
  Future signUp() async {
    final isValid = formKey.currentState!.validate();
    if (!isValid) return;

    showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (context) => const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ));
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: emailController.text.trim(),
          password: passwordController.text.trim());
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      print(e);

      Utils.showSnackBar(e.message);
    }
    navigatorKey.currentState!.popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
  }
```

Comment: you could use `FireStore` . you could create collection for each user with it Uid then store name and other feild on it . for code just after that Authentication end successfully you could get Uid then perform saving data